# How to add info window in angular google maps with out marker?

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, ng-map

I am trying below angular plugin for google maps.

https://ngmap.github.io/

can any one please help me how to add info window, with out a marker ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

According to [Info Windows](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows):

> Typically you will attach an info window to a marker, but you can also
>   attach an info window to a *specific latitude/longitude*

The following example demonstrates how to attach an info window to a *specific latitude/longitude*:

```js
angular.module('ngMap').run(function($rootScope, NgMap) {
  NgMap.getMap().then(function(map) {
    $rootScope.map = map;
    var iw = map.infoWindows.bar;
    iw.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922));
    map.showInfoWindow('bar');
  });
});
```

```css
.ng-map-info-window {
    background-color: navy;
    color: #fff;
  }
  .ng-map-info-window div:first-child > div:nth-child(1) {
    border-top-color: navy !important;
  }
  .ng-map-info-window div:first-child > div:nth-child(3) div {
    background-color: transparent !important;
  }
  .ng-map-info-window div:first-child > div:nth-child(4) {
    background-color: transparent !important;
  }
```

```html
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgit.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps/master/build/scripts/ng-map.js"></script> 
<div ng-app="ngMap">
    Info Windows
    <br/> This example displays a marker at the center of Australia. When the user clicks the marker, an info window opens.
    <ng-map default-style="true" center="-25.363882,131.044922" zoom="4">
      <!--marker id="foo" position="-25.363882,131.044922" on-click="map.showInfoWindow('bar')">
      </marker-->
      <info-window id="bar" >
        <div ng-non-bindable>
          <div id="siteNotice"></div>
          <h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Uluru</h1>
          <div id="bodyContent">
            <p><b>Uluru</b>, also referred to as <b>Ayers Rock</b>, is a large sandstone rock formation in the southern part
              of the Northern Territory, central Australia. It lies 335 km (208 mi) south west of the nearest large town,
              Alice Springs; 450 km (280 mi) by road. Kata Tjuta and Uluru are the two major features of the Uluru - Kata
              Tjuta National Park. Uluru is sacred to the Pitjantjatjara and Yankunytjatjara, the Aboriginal people of the
              area. It has many springs, waterholes, rock caves and ancient paintings. Uluru is listed as a World Heritage
              Site.</p>
            <p>Attribution: Uluru, <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uluru&oldid=297882194">
            http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uluru</a> (last visited June 22, 2009).</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </info-window>
    </ng-map>
  </div>
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vgrem/zsanhsqu/)